# path1.resolve(path2) return path2 even path2.isAbsolute()=false and path2 is not empty

Tags: java, windows, nio, nio2

Given the following code

```
    Path p1 = Paths.get("\\photos\\vacation");
    Path p2 = Paths.get("\\yellowstone");
    System.out.println(p1.isAbsolute());  // false
    System.out.println(p2.isAbsolute());  // false
    System.out.println(p1.resolve(p2));  // \yellowstone
```

JavaDoc says:

> public abstract Path resolve(Path other)
>
> Resolve the given path against this path.
>
> **If the other parameter is an absolute path then this method trivially returns other**.
>
> If other is an empty path then this method trivially returns this
>   path.
>
> Otherwise this method considers this path to be a directory and
>   resolves the given path against this path. In the simplest case, the
>   given path does not have a root component, in which case this method
>   joins the given path to this path and returns a resulting path that
>   ends with the given path. Where the given path has a root component
>   then resolution is highly implementation dependent and therefore
>   unspecified.

Running on Windows the paths are not absolute, but its still retuns p2 as a result; I couldnt understand that behaviour. What I am missing?

Comment: They both say the path is not absolute, because the drive letter (or "root component" as the quoted text calls it) is missing. Since `p2` is fully qualified from the root of the drive, then only part of the result that would come from `p1` is the drive letter, and `p1` doesn't have that either, so result is same as `p2`. As it should be!! --- But answer this: If you didn't expect result to be same as `p2`, what did you expect result to be?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your code?

Comment: Notice it does not say “If *and only if* the other parameter is an absolute path then this method trivially returns other.”  As you have observed, there are situations where it can return p2, even if p2 is not absolute.

Comment: This is a code from question of oracle OCP certification exam